# Getting sum of each day of last 30 days

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I can get a list of each day of last 30 days row by row with this query and it works..
But I don't think that it is the best one since the "WHERE" part is messed up. I draw a graph and I just want to get daily_total_invoice_amount for sum of each day of last 30 days.

```
SELECT
  sum(b.invoice_amount) daily_total_invoice_amount,
  extract(day from a.order_creation_date)   as day,
  extract(month from a.order_creation_date) as month
FROM orders a
  INNER JOIN order_items b
    ON a.order_id = b.order_id
WHERE
  order_creation_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 MONTH' + INTERVAL '2 DAY') 
AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    GROUP BY month, day
    order by month DESC, day DESC
```

Comment: You could simply your WHERE clause to `between current_date - 30 and current_date + 1`

Comment: Have you considered generate_series?

Comment: @Vérace Honestly I don't have any idea. I will check it out. It would be great if you could have shown how to do it with it. It seems like ( I googled ) it is done for this kind of queries.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-generate-series-to-get-continuous-results) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html).

Comment: Is your column `orders.order_creation_date` data type `date` as the name indicates? Can there be days without any orders and do you still want a row for such days in the result? All your questions should include your version of Postgres and table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing data types and constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why include *tomorrow* (`CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'`)? A future date in `order_creation_date` would normally indicate a data error. I would not even include *today* in the statistic, since that is typically incomplete and misleading until the day is over. Consequently I use the last 30 days up until *yesterday* in my query.

Assuming `order_creation_date` is an actual `date`, just `GROUP BY` and `ORDER  BY` that date, that's simpler an cheaper than using extracted month and day numbers for the same. If it's not a `date`, but a `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, just cast to `date` to group by the day: `o.order_creation_date::date`. Be aware that the result depends on the `timezone` setting of the session when dealing with `timestamptz` (Day boundaries are defined by the time zone.)

Also assuming you want a result row for *every* single one of the 30 days. To make sure, days without orders don't go missing, generate the series of days with `generate_series()` and `LEFT JOIN` to that. You can generate timestamps, but I use the simpler integer variant while we are operating with dates. We can just subtract an `integer` from a `date` to subtract days.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - i AS date
     , sum(oi.invoice_amount) AS daily_total_invoice_amount
FROM   generate_series (1, 30) i -- to return exactly 30 rows
LEFT   JOIN orders      o ON o.order_creation_date = CURRENT_DATE - i
LEFT   JOIN order_items oi USING (order_id)
GROUP  BY i    -- effectively group by days
ORDER  BY i;   -- effectively descending dates
```

Comment: I include today because I would like to show today's total amount in the chart as well, it is a product need, otherwise I agree with you. It is just a preference, as we can get current day's stats in analytics with additional option.


I run this query but I got this
[42712] ERROR: table name "i" specified more than once
Details

Comment: I solved it by changing i to any letter ( x ) LEFT   JOIN order_items i(x) USING (order_id) and  sum(i.invoice_amount) i(x ). But the result ( daily_total_invoice_amount ) that I get is not same as I get from regular query. They are mostly null ( all of my field has value no 0 ) and daily_total_invoice_amount is pretty low. I will try to understand the whole query to make it work. I am sure this is the right way.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate table alias. Fixed. There are often several good ways with SQL. I am just proposing *one*. The best solution depends on the actual environment and exact requirements. You didn't disclose a whole lot of information - starting with the table definition. My solution is based on data type `date`, as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround, base on Vérace Apr 5 at 20:18 first referenced article, the performance is not optimal, but it works.

```
select date(d) ds
, count(distinct case when c.ds = date(d) then c.user_id else null end) d0_user_count
, count(distinct case when c.ds <= date(d) and c.ds >= date(d) - 3 then c.user_id else null end) d3_user_count
, count(distinct c.user_id) d5_user_count
from generate_series(
  current_date - interval '30 day', 
  current_date, 
  '1 day'
) d
left join user_click c
on c.ds <= date(d) and c.ds >= date(d) - 5
group by date(d)
;
```